# Can the Java stream consume / destroy the source collection at the same time?

Tags: java, java-stream

Sample:

```
public class Dummy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
        List<Integer> squareNumbers = numbers.stream().map(x -> x * x).collect(Collectors.toList());
        // I don't need `numbers` anymore.
        System.out.println(squareNumbers);
    }
}
```

After creating `squareNumbers` collection, I don't need `numbers` collection anymore.
I want to release the `numbers` collection elements as soon as possible (to free the memory).
Can I achieve this by using Java streams?

Answer (score 4):

That is not how Java garbage collection works. Streams do not 'consume' or 'destroy' collections. As long as there is a reference (in this case the local variable `numbers`), the object will not get garbage collected. In other words, the object will become eligible for GC after the methods ends (though potentially an intelligent JVM might allow for it to be collected when the local variable is no longer used for the remainder of the method).

In the method as shown, you really don't need to do anything, as the method ends soon after the last use of `numbers`.

Also, garbage collection in Java doesn't run immediately when an object becomes eligible for garbage collection, it might take some time before it will get collected (depending on a multitude of factors, including the actual garbage collector and its configuration).

You could do one of the following:

1. Inline the variable `numbers`:

   ```java
   List<Integer> squareNumbers = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).stream().map(x -> x * x).collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```
2. Explicitly `null` the local variable after its last use.

However, neither is likely to have a significant benefit, unless the remainder of the method is very long-running. And doing this (and especially option 2) without a very good reason leads to hard to read code, and it will likely not help at all if the JVM is smart enough or if the method ends soon after. Option 2 might even actively interfere with some optimizations (though I'm guessing here).

If memory is really a concern, it would be better to remove the use of boxed integers, and use primitive arrays (i.e. `int[]`), a normal for-loop, and - potentially - reuse the same array.

For example:

```java
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3 };
for (int idx = 0; idx < numbers.length; idx++) {
    numbers[idx] = numbers[idx] * numbers[idx];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```

Using `IntStream.iterate` with a limit as [suggested by MC Emperor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70279352/466862) (or `IntStream.of` if the input isn't contiguous) can also reduce memory consumption. However, keep in mind that streams are complex, stateful objects, which comes with their own memory overhead.

Comment: I'm afraid we didn't understand each other in one thing (maybe my question was too imprecise). By consuming input collection, I meant removing elements from the input list (`numbers`) when the element is already processed by the stream and is no longer needed.
In my opinion, in this case, such deleted (and detached) collection elements (items) can be released by the JVM.
This my piece of Java code is just an example - not a real code.
In my case: my input collections processed by streams have many element (1M or more).
The similar consumption can be achieved by using iterator.remove().

Comment: @adaslaw That is indeed an entirely different question, and there is no default way to have it empty the collection, though you might be able to achieve it using a custom Spliterator that removes the elements before returning them.

Comment: Instead of `Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).stream()` you can use `Stream.of(1, 2, 3)` or in this case, you may even use `IntStream.of(1, 2, 3).map(x -> x * x).boxed() .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @adaslaw there are several misconceptions on your side here. The list returned by `Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)` does not support removal to begin with, calling `remove` on the list or an iterator returned by this list will throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. If you use an `ArrayList` instead and remove elements while iterating in order, you will get a quadratic time complexity, in other words, horrible performance. When you don’t use `numbers` after the operation, the best option is to let the garbage collector do its work by *not* modifying the list, as modifying an object hinders GC.

Comment: @Holger My guess was that use of `Arrays.asList(...)` was primarily for simplification.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel well, an oversimplification then. A general solution has to take into account that the list might not be modifiable. I already addressed the most likely scenario that the list is `ArrayList` if mutable. Removing elements while iterating over an `ArrayList` with 1M elements, is a really bad idea. And if it’s a `LinkedList`, the negative impact on garbage collection would be even worse.

Comment: @Holger I believe this could have a negative impact on GC, but I also believe sometimes it's more important to reduce the memory usage (paying for it CPU usage).
Btw: I agree that this trick is not acceptable for `ArrayList` but it could be acceptable for  `LinkedList` (IMO).

Comment: Since `LinkedList` consumes far more memory than `ArrayList` to begin with, it would only pay off memory wise, if the objects were very large. In that case, using a queue like `ArrayDeque` would make more sense. Queues are designed for remove-while-iterating scenarios.

Answer (score 3):

You generally should not care about this. `numbers` is a *local variable*, and as soon as it goes out of scope, it is eligible for garbage collection. The JVM will release the used memory if it decides that it is necessary at that time.

If you really worry about memory, then don't create a `List` in the first place.

You could create a stream directly, without first storing into a list. There are several options to do this, depending on which integers are used:

- Integers known at compile time, or from an `int[]`.

  ```java
  IntStream.of(2, 3, 5, 7)
  ```
- Subsequent integers (e.g. *1, 2, 3, …*)

  ```java
  IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 8)
  ```
- Non-subsequent integers, whose values are defined by some formula:

  ```java
  IntStream.iterate(1, i -> 2 * i + 1)
      .limit(25)
  ```

Then you could directly operate on the created stream<sup>1</sup>:

```java
    .map(n -> n * n)
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I created an `IntStream` instead of a `Stream` to avoid boxing/unboxing overhead, as [suggested by Mark Rotteveel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70279268/can-the-java-stream-consume-destroy-the-source-collection-at-the-same-time/70279352?noredirect=1#comment124234857_70279352) in the comments.  `boxed()` is used to convert to a `Stream<Integer>`.

Comment: It might make sense to use `IntStream.iterate` to avoid boxing overhead until creating the list (or replacing it with `toArray()` to obtain an `int[]`  instead),

Comment: Good point. Updated the post.

Comment: Also, `IntStream.of(1, 2, 3)` can be used instead of `Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3).stream()`, this might be helpful if the list of input numbers isn't contiguous.

Comment: `IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 3)` will perform way better than `IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1).limit(3)`. For small ranges, even `IntStream.of(1, 2, 3)` will perform better than `iterate` + `limit`.

Comment: @Holger Very interesting. I updated the post.